# Do I have to loop through each 'page' of orders to get all orders in one WooComerce REST Api query?

Tags: rest, api, woocommerce, orders, knime

I've built a KNIME workflow that helps me analyse (sales) data from numerous channels. In the past I used to export all orders manually and use an XSLX or CSV reader but I want to do it via WooCommerce's REST API to reduce manual labor.

I would like to be able to receive all orders up until now from a single query. So far, I only get as many as the # I fill in for &per_page=X. But if I fill in like 1000, it gives an error. This + my common sense give me the feeling I'm thinking the wrong way!

If it is not possible, is looping through all pages the second best thing?

I've managed to connect to the api via basic auth. The following query returns orders, but only 10:

I've tried increasing the number per_page but I do not think this is the right way to get all orders in one table.

```
https://XXXX.nl/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?consumer_key=XXXX&consumer_secret=XXXX
```

My current mindset would like to be able to receive all orders up until now from a single query. But it personally also feels like that this is not the common way to do it. Is looping through all pages the second best thing?

Thanks in advance for your responses. I am more of a data analist than a data engineer or scientist and I hope your answers will help me towards my goal of being more of a scientist :)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible by passing params "per_page" with the request

```
per_page    integer Maximum number of items to be returned in result set. Default is 10.
```

Try -1 as the value

https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#list-all-orders

Comment: I get no output and a 400 error if I fill in over 100. Maybe I am all wrong but I think this is not the correct way to do it.

Comment: Try like this in URL .   &filter[per_page]=-1